# Sum over an array component of a multi-dimensional derived type (without do loop)?

Tags: fortran

I have a derived type array, where the derived types can also be arrays.  Is there any way to sum over elements without resorting to a do loop?

```
program main

   type t_couple
      real :: income(2) = 5
   end type t_couple

   type(t_couple) :: couple(2)

   print *, " sum 1 ", sum(couple(1)%income)  ! works fine
   print *, " sum 2 ", sum(couple%income)     ! doesn't work

end program main
```

> %F90-E-ERROR, A component cannot be an array if the encompassing structure is an array.

Of course we have all seen this error message many times and can write a do loop to solve this, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler and more concise way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an implicit loop:

```
print *, " sum 2 ", sum( [( couple(i)%income, i=1,size(couple))] )
```

Comment: Well, +1 for doing it on one line but it's still a loop...  But probably there is no way to do it without a loop.

Comment: @JohnE At least I don't know of any other way...